# Gotta Match Them All! Write a regex to match the original 151 Pokemon but no subsequent Pokemon

Tags: code-golf, regular-expression

The original 151 Pokemon, in an array format suitable for initializers:

```
["Bulbasaur", "Ivysaur", "Venusaur", "Charmander", "Charmeleon", "Charizard", "Squirtle", "Wartortle", "Blastoise", "Caterpie", "Metapod", "Butterfree", "Weedle", "Kakuna", "Beedrill", "Pidgey", "Pidgeotto", "Pidgeot", "Rattata", "Raticate", "Spearow", "Fearow", "Ekans", "Arbok", "Pikachu", "Raichu", "Sandshrew", "Sandslash", "Nidorina", "Nidoqueen", "Nidoran", "Nidorino", "Nidoking", "Clefairy", "Clefable", "Vulpix", "Ninetales", "Jigglypuff", "Wigglytuff", "Zubat", "Golbat", "Oddish", "Gloom", "Vileplume", "Paras", "Parasect", "Venonat", "Venomoth", "Diglett", "Dugtrio", "Meowth", "Persian", "Psyduck", "Golduck", "Mankey", "Primeape", "Growlithe", "Arcanine", "Poliwag", "Poliwhirl", "Poliwrath", "Abra", "Kadabra", "Alakazam", "Machop", "Machoke", "Machamp", "Bellsprout", "Weepinbell", "Victreebel", "Tentacool", "Tentacruel", "Geodude", "Graveler", "Golem", "Ponyta", "Rapidash", "Slowpoke", "Slowbro", "Magnemite", "Magneton", "Farfetch'd", "Doduo", "Dodrio", "Seel", "Dewgong", "Grimer", "Muk", "Shellder", "Cloyster", "Gastly", "Haunter", "Gengar", "Onix", "Drowzee", "Hypno", "Krabby", "Kingler", "Voltorb", "Electrode", "Exeggcute", "Exeggutor", "Cubone", "Marowak", "Hitmonlee", "Hitmonchan", "Lickitung", "Koffing", "Weezing", "Rhyhorn", "Rhydon", "Chansey", "Tangela", "Kangaskhan", "Horsea", "Seadra", "Goldeen", "Seaking", "Staryu", "Starmie", "Mr. Mime", "Scyther", "Jynx", "Electabuzz", "Magmar", "Pinsir", "Tauros", "Magikarp", "Gyarados", "Lapras", "Ditto", "Eevee", "Vaporeon", "Jolteon", "Flareon", "Porygon", "Omanyte", "Omastar", "Kabuto", "Kabutops", "Aerodactyl", "Snorlax", "Articuno", "Zapdos", "Moltres", "Dratini", "Dragonair", "Dragonite", "Mewtwo", "Mew"]
```

I have omitted the male-female Nidoran distinction because it shouldn't affect any regex generation.

And all subsequent Pokemon:

```
["Chikorita", "Bayleef", "Meganium", "Cyndaquil", "Quilava", "Typhlosion", "Totodile", "Croconaw", "Feraligatr", "Sentret", "Furret", "Hoothoot", "Noctowl", "Ledyba", "Ledian", "Spinarak", "Ariados", "Crobat", "Chinchou", "Lanturn", "Pichu", "Cleffa", "Igglybuff", "Togepi", "Togetic", "Natu", "Xatu", "Mareep", "Flaaffy", "Ampharos", "Bellossom", "Marill", "Azumarill", "Sudowoodo", "Politoed", "Hoppip", "Skiploom", "Jumpluff", "Aipom", "Sunkern", "Sunflora", "Yanma", "Wooper", "Quagsire", "Espeon", "Umbreon", "Murkrow", "Slowking", "Misdreavus", "Unown", "Wobbuffet", "Girafarig", "Pineco", "Forretress", "Dunsparce", "Gligar", "Steelix", "Snubbull", "Granbull", "Qwilfish", "Scizor", "Shuckle", "Heracross", "Sneasel", "Teddiursa", "Ursaring", "Slugma", "Magcargo", "Swinub", "Piloswine", "Corsola", "Remoraid", "Octillery", "Delibird", "Mantine", "Skarmory", "Houndour", "Houndoom", "Kingdra", "Phanpy", "Donphan", "Porygon2", "Stantler", "Smeargle", "Tyrogue", "Hitmontop", "Smoochum", "Elekid", "Magby", "Miltank", "Blissey", "Raikou", "Entei", "Suicune", "Larvitar", "Pupitar", "Tyranitar", "Lugia", "Ho-Oh", "Celebi", "Treecko", "Grovyle", "Sceptile", "Torchic", "Combusken", "Blaziken", "Mudkip", "Marshtomp", "Swampert", "Poochyena", "Mightyena", "Zigzagoon", "Linoone", "Wurmple", "Silcoon", "Beautifly", "Cascoon", "Dustox", "Lotad", "Lombre", "Ludicolo", "Seedot", "Nuzleaf", "Shiftry", "Taillow", "Swellow", "Wingull", "Pelipper", "Ralts", "Kirlia", "Gardevoir", "Surskit", "Masquerain", "Shroomish", "Breloom", "Slakoth", "Vigoroth", "Slaking", "Nincada", "Ninjask", "Shedinja", "Whismur", "Loudred", "Exploud", "Makuhita", "Hariyama", "Azurill", "Nosepass", "Skitty", "Delcatty", "Sableye", "Mawile", "Aron", "Lairon", "Aggron", "Meditite", "Medicham", "Electrike", "Manectric", "Plusle", "Minun", "Volbeat", "Illumise", "Roselia", "Gulpin", "Swalot", "Carvanha", "Sharpedo", "Wailmer", "Wailord", "Numel", "Camerupt", "Torkoal", "Spoink", "Grumpig", "Spinda", "Trapinch", "Vibrava", "Flygon", "Cacnea", "Cacturne", "Swablu", "Altaria", "Zangoose", "Seviper", "Lunatone", "Solrock", "Barboach", "Whiscash", "Corphish", "Crawdaunt", "Baltoy", "Claydol", "Lileep", "Cradily", "Anorith", "Armaldo", "Feebas", "Milotic", "Castform", "Kecleon", "Shuppet", "Banette", "Duskull", "Dusclops", "Tropius", "Chimecho", "Absol", "Wynaut", "Snorunt", "Glalie", "Spheal", "Sealeo", "Walrein", "Clamperl", "Huntail", "Gorebyss", "Relicanth", "Luvdisc", "Bagon", "Shelgon", "Salamence", "Beldum", "Metang", "Metagross", "Regirock", "Regice", "Registeel", "Latias", "Latios", "Kyogre", "Groudon", "Rayquaza", "Jirachi", "Deoxys", "Turtwig", "Grotle", "Torterra", "Chimchar", "Monferno", "Infernape", "Piplup", "Prinplup", "Empoleon", "Starly", "Staravia", "Staraptor", "Bidoof", "Bibarel", "Kricketot", "Kricketune", "Shinx", "Luxio", "Luxray", "Budew", "Roserade", "Cranidos", "Rampardos", "Shieldon", "Bastiodon", "Burmy", "Wormadam", "Mothim", "Combee", "Vespiquen", "Pachirisu", "Buizel", "Floatzel", "Cherubi", "Cherrim", "Shellos", "Gastrodon", "Ambipom", "Drifloon", "Drifblim", "Buneary", "Lopunny", "Mismagius", "Honchkrow", "Glameow", "Purugly", "Chingling", "Stunky", "Skuntank", "Bronzor", "Bronzong", "Bonsly", "Mime Jr.", "Happiny", "Chatot", "Spiritomb", "Gible", "Gabite", "Garchomp", "Munchlax", "Riolu", "Lucario", "Hippopotas", "Hippowdon", "Skorupi", "Drapion", "Croagunk", "Toxicroak", "Carnivine", "Finneon", "Lumineon", "Mantyke", "Snover", "Abomasnow", "Weavile", "Magnezone", "Lickilicky", "Rhyperior", "Tangrowth", "Electivire", "Magmortar", "Togekiss", "Yanmega", "Leafeon", "Glaceon", "Gliscor", "Mamoswine", "Porygon-Z", "Gallade", "Probopass", "Dusknoir", "Froslass", "Rotom", "Uxie", "Mesprit", "Azelf", "Dialga", "Palkia", "Heatran", "Regigigas", "Giratina", "Cresselia", "Phione", "Manaphy", "Darkrai", "Shaymin", "Arceus", "Victini", "Snivy", "Servine", "Serperior", "Tepig", "Pignite", "Emboar", "Oshawott", "Dewott", "Samurott", "Patrat", "Watchog", "Lillipup", "Herdier", "Stoutland", "Purrloin", "Liepard", "Pansage", "Simisage", "Pansear", "Simisear", "Panpour", "Simipour", "Munna", "Musharna", "Pidove", "Tranquill", "Unfezant", "Blitzle", "Zebstrika", "Roggenrola", "Boldore", "Gigalith", "Woobat", "Swoobat", "Drilbur", "Excadrill", "Audino", "Timburr", "Gurdurr", "Conkeldurr", "Tympole", "Palpitoad", "Seismitoad", "Throh", "Sawk", "Sewaddle", "Swadloon", "Leavanny", "Venipede", "Whirlipede", "Scolipede", "Cottonee", "Whimsicott", "Petilil", "Lilligant", "Basculin", "Sandile", "Krokorok", "Krookodile", "Darumaka", "Darmanitan", "Maractus", "Dwebble", "Crustle", "Scraggy", "Scrafty", "Sigilyph", "Yamask", "Cofagrigus", "Tirtouga", "Carracosta", "Archen", "Archeops", "Trubbish", "Garbodor", "Zorua", "Zoroark", "Minccino", "Cinccino", "Gothita", "Gothorita", "Gothitelle", "Solosis", "Duosion", "Reuniclus", "Ducklett", "Swanna", "Vanillite", "Vanillish", "Vanilluxe", "Deerling", "Sawsbuck", "Emolga", "Karrablast", "Escavalier", "Foongus", "Amoonguss", "Frillish", "Jellicent", "Alomomola", "Joltik", "Galvantula", "Ferroseed", "Ferrothorn", "Klink", "Klang", "Klinklang", "Tynamo", "Eelektrik", "Eelektross", "Elgyem", "Beheeyem", "Litwick", "Lampent", "Chandelure", "Axew", "Fraxure", "Haxorus", "Cubchoo", "Beartic", "Cryogonal", "Shelmet", "Accelgor", "Stunfisk", "Mienfoo", "Mienshao", "Druddigon", "Golett", "Golurk", "Pawniard", "Bisharp", "Bouffalant", "Rufflet", "Braviary", "Vullaby", "Mandibuzz", "Heatmor", "Durant", "Deino", "Zweilous", "Hydreigon", "Larvesta", "Volcarona", "Cobalion", "Terrakion", "Virizion", "Tornadus", "Thundurus", "Reshiram", "Zekrom", "Landorus", "Kyurem", "Keldeo", "Meloetta", "Genesect", "Chespin", "Quilladin", "Chesnaught", "Fennekin", "Braixen", "Delphox", "Froakie", "Frogadier", "Greninja", "Bunnelby", "Diggersby", "Fletchling", "Fletchinder", "Talonflame", "Scatterbug", "Spewpa", "Vivillon", "Litleo", "Pyroar", "Flabébé", "Floette", "Florges", "Skiddo", "Gogoat", "Pancham", "Pangoro", "Furfrou", "Espurr", "Meowstic", "Honedge", "Doublade", "Aegislash", "Spritzee", "Aromatisse", "Swirlix", "Slurpuff", "Inkay", "Malamar", "Binacle", "Barbaracle", "Skrelp", "Dragalge", "Clauncher", "Clawitzer", "Helioptile", "Heliolisk", "Tyrunt", "Tyrantrum", "Amaura", "Aurorus", "Sylveon", "Hawlucha", "Dedenne", "Carbink", "Goomy", "Sliggoo", "Goodra", "Klefki", "Phantump", "Trevenant", "Pumpkaboo", "Gourgeist", "Bergmite", "Avalugg", "Noibat", "Noivern", "Xerneas", "Yveltal", "Zygarde", "Diancie"]
```

Comment: You decided Mew isn't an "original"? Poor Mew...

Comment: I'm with @Bigtoes, why are we excluding Mew?

Comment: Fixed, since everyone complained. I'm not a Pokemon fan.

Comment: How are you gonna check whether the answers are valid?

Comment: @flawr Peter Norvig wrote a regex golf validation function along with the solver.

Comment: You forgot Hoopa and Volcanion at the end.

Comment: @JoeZ. I'm going by the [Wikipedia list of Pokemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pokemon). At the time I had compiled this list (several months ago) Hoopa was not on the list. Volcanion is not mentioned in the article.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Most flavours, <s>332</s> <s>331</s> <s>326</s> <s>325</s> 304 bytes

```
tly|glo|pix|y.?t|key|d.*sh|dod|iw|ung|r.*me|sa?.r$|ras|abr|aic|mac|g.e.*t|t.i?o$|wb|z..d|wg|kh|rs.a|le?s|lld|a.ow|yh|pn|(or.+o|g.*le|(gm|ub.?|o.l|(id.+|a.+n|olt|onc).).).$|^(..(.([lx]?$|g.y|fa|i?ka)|an?s|yd|eg)|.?ra?[bt]|vi.*e|f.?ar|ko|gy)|(t.r.|rt|ow.*|v|w).e|[kt]a.*u|g.l[abd]|e(ak|no|n.a|.dr|o.t|.*od)
```

Thanks to EMBLEM I had to revamp and restart, building a regex with a back-and-forth relay of manual part selection and Peter Norvig's golfer. Saved a whole bunch of bytes, and probably more is still possible, so I guess it was worth it?

[Tested on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eU2xP9/9) (includes `hoopa` and `volcanion`, since they aren't matched anyway)

If anyone's wondering, `seel` is the biggest pain to match, thanks to `registeel` and `seedot` in the other list. Other hard-to-match Pokemon include `hitmonchan` (thanks to `hitmontop` and `chandelure/donphan`),`jolteon` (thanks to `joltik` and half the `eevee` evolutions) and `porygon` (thanks to `flygon` and `porygon2/porygon-z`)

Comment: `[lx]?` can safely be changed to `l?x?` to save a byte