# What is the shortest regular expression (REGEX) you can create for file extensions for image formats?

Tags: code-golf, regular-expression

What is the shortest regular expression (REGEX) you can create for file extensions for all of the following image file formats (photographs, paintings, sketches, and drawings)?

```None
.ACAD
.AFD
.AFP
.AOM
.AOMA
.APNG
.ASCII
.AVIF
.AVIFAV
.BMP
.BPG
.CABAC
.CDEC
.CDR
.CDRAW
.CGM
.CHEVC
.CIEC
.CIPA
.CMYK
.COLLADA
.CRT
.CWC
.DEEP
.DGN
.DML
.DRAW
.DXFDXF
.DXML
.ECW
.EMF
.EPS
.ERDAS
.EXIF
.FAMF
.FCCBY
.FDRW
.FIFF
.FITS
.FLIF
.FPGF
.FRIFF
.FVRML
.FXD
.GEM
.GIF
.GIMP
.GLE
.GMNG
.GMPEG
.GPNG
.GSVG
.HDR
.HEIF
.HEIFFAVIFAVHEIFAV
.HEVC
.HPGL
.HSF
.HVIF
.ICC
.ICO
.IESC
.IESCD
.IGES
.ILBM
.IMAGINE
.IMAGINEIMG
.IMG
.IMML
.INDD
.IPA
.ISGI
.ISO
.JFIF
.JFIFJPEG
.JPEG
.JPEGHDR
.JPEGJPEG
.JPG
.JPL
.JPS
.KKRA
.LCM
.LPCL
.LXAML
.LZW
.LZWLZW
.MANIAC
.MDP
.MEMF
.MML
.MOV
.MPO
.MSID
.MSIDSID
.MWMF
.NAPLPS
.NASA
.OBJ
.OCR
.ODG
.OGEX
.OGL
.PAM
.PBM
.PCB
.PCLIP
.PCPT
.PCX
.PDF
.PGFTZ
.PGM
.PGML
.PICT
.PLBM
.PLY
.PNG
.PNM
.PNS
.POVR
.PPDN
.PPM
.PPSP
.PRC
.PSD
.PST
.PXMP
.QCC
.RAW
.RGBE
.RGIS
.RIFF
.RISCOS
.RSX
.SAI
.SAISAI
.SISO
.STEP
.STL
.SUSKP
.SVG
.SVGC
.SWF
.SXML
.TARGA
.TGATGA
.TIF
.TIFF
.TVG
.TVP
.VDI
.VICAR
.VML
.VRML
.WEBP
.WMF
.WPM
.XCF
.XGL
.XISF
.XML
.XMP
.XPS
.XVL
```

---

## Scoring Function

The scoring function will be the number of ASCII characters in your regex

Note: only [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters are allowed in this competition.

---

May the best **regex** win!

Comment: Why is there a seemingly arbitary ASCII-only restriction?

Comment: Also the list of extensions is more or less arbitrary, as there could be many many more

Comment: @SuperStormer You asked why the regex must be ASCII-only. The answer is that all of the image file extensions provided in the code golf competition rules are written using the letters in the set {`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, `G`, `H`, `I`, `J`, `K`, `L`, `M`, `N`, `O`, `P`, `Q`, `R`, `S`, `T`, `U`, `V`, `W`, `X`, `Y`, `Z`}. For example, `.JPEG` does not use any characters outside of the ASCII character set. Almost all standard suffixes for image filetypes use ASCII characters.

Comment: That doesn't mean you should ban all other chars

Comment: ahem: wtf is HEIFFAVIFAVHEIFAV? never heard of that in my life and google just thinks im crazy

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of [Gotta Match Them All!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47582/66833). The core task is identical ("create a regex that only matches this list of strings"), even if the list of matches is different.

Answer (score 1):

## 752 bytes

```
^\.((HEIFFAVIFAVHE|AV)IFAV|(IMAGINEIM|J(PEG|FIF)JPE|GMPE|APN|G([MP]N|SV)|BP)G|I(MAGINE|ESC)|M(SIDSID|OV)|((JPEG)?HD|POV|OC)R|(C(OLLAD|IP)|T(GAT|AR)G|KKR|IP)A|(MANIA|C(HEV|DE|IE|W)|CABA|HEV|PR)C|(LZWLZ|C?DRA|FDR|EC)W|(SAISA|ASCI|ISG)I|(DXFDX|F(RIF|IF|PG)|(EX|FL)I|H(VI|S)|FAM|M[EW]M|RIF|EM|PD|SW|WM)F|(R(ISCO|GI)|E(RDA|P)|FIT|IGE|XP)S|NA(PLPS|SA)|FCCBY|I(ESCD|C[CO]|MG|SO)|P(G(FTZ|ML)|P(DN|M)|CPT|ICT|C[BX]|LY|N[GMS]|S[DT])|V(ICAR|DI)|(P(CLI|PS|XM)|S(USK|TE)|DEE|GIM|BM|MD)P|((FVR|LXA|SX)M|DX?M|HPG|IMM|LPC|VR?M|MM)L|A(VIF|OM)|HEIF|J(PEG|FIF)|MSID|A(OMA|F[DP])|CMYK|(ACA|IND|FX)D|OGEX|R(GBE|AW|SX)|S(VGC|ISO|TL)|T(IFF|V[GP])|(ILB|P(LB|[AB])|CG|GE|LC)M|W(EBP|PM)|X(ISF|M[LP]|[GV]L|CF)|CDR|LZW|PGM|S(AI|VG)|[TG]IF|JP[GLS]|O(BJ|DG|GL)|DGN|CRT|QCC|GLE|MPO)$
```

Naïve impementation, created with the help of [this tool](https://www.javainuse.com/rexgenerator)

Comment: ooh, i think `S(VGC|ISO|TL)` can be `S(VGC?|AI|ISO|TL)` and then you can remove `|S(AI|VG)`, correct me if im wrong though, cant tell if its like, nested in some structure where that isnt an option